# Clear data in AWS Neptune

Tags: curl, postman, sparql, rdf, amazon-neptune

I am trying to run simple CLEAR and DELETE SPARQL queries and keep getting back:

```
    Malformed query: Encountered \" \"clear\" \"CLEAR \"\" at line
    1, column 1.\n Was expecting one of:\n \"base\" ...\n \"prefix\" 
...\n \"select\" ...\n \"construct\" ...\n \ "describe\" ...\n \"ask\" ...\n
```

Are the CLEAR and DELETE queries not supported? or does Neptune have another way of clearing the graph in the instance.

Thanks

Comment: how do you run the command? note, SPARQL Update command is different from querying, i.e. you should use `update` instead of `query` param - do something like `curl https://your-neptune-endpoint:port/sparql
    -d "update=YOUR_UPDATE_COMMAND"`

Comment: I am running it through postman with the Headers with Content-Type = application/sparql-query and Accept = application/sparql-results+json. I am using an POST request to send a simple CLEAR [ GRAPH <uri> ] to remove all triples

Comment: `application/sparql-update`

Comment: Thanks! is there any other headers. I'm using the simple query `DELETE [ <uri> ] { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }` and I'm still getting the `"Malformed query: Encountered \" \"delete\" \"DELETE \"\" at line 1, column 1.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"base\" ...\n    \"prefix\" ...\n    \"drop entailments\" ...\n    \"create entailments\" ...\n    \"enable entailments\" ...\n    \"disable entailments\" ...\n    \"load\" ...\n    \"clear\" ` I assume DELETE would be supported on Neptune, not sure why it is not detecting it

Comment: Solved. The 'CLEAR ALL' Command worked. I guess only certain commands are supported on the SPARQL UPDATE implementation

Comment: @jtrugman - Do review the answer and let me know if it clarifies your doubts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Word of Caution: The answer contains examples to DELETE all your data,
>   so be extra careful when you execute these queries in your database.

Neptune does support CLEAR and DELETE. CLEAR and DELETE are UPDATE operations, so you can do them in two ways:

1) Use "update=" in the request params

```
curl http://endpoint:8182/sparql -d "update=DELETE DATA { <http://x> <http://y> <http://z> }” 

OR

curl http://localhost:8182/sparql -d "update=DELETE WHERE { ... }” 

You can use a similar one for CLEAR.
```

2) Use Content-Type Header (application/sparql-update) and use the query directly in request params.

```
curl http://endpoint:8182/sparql -H "Content-Type: application/sparql-update" -d "DELETE DATA { <http://x> <http://y> <http://z> }”
```

It looks like you tried a mix of both, and possibly got the combination incorrect. Neptune is fully SPARQL 1.1 compliant, so if you see something to not be working, do let us know. In almost all cases, the request would not have adhered to the SPARQL HTTP spec.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks

Comment: With `awscurl`, only the second variant seems to work for me: `awscurl -X POST --region "${region}" --service neptune-db  --access_key "${access_key}" --secret_key "${secret_key}" "https://${url}:${port}/sparql" -d 'DROP ALL' -H "Content-Type: application/sparql-update"`